# Dynamic Online/Offline Speech Recognition with SFSpeechRecognizer

Tags: ios, sfspeechrecognizer

I am using SFSpeechRecognizer and SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest as documented by Apple in the [Recognizing Speech in Live Audio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/recognizing_speech_in_live_audio) example project.

It works fine online.

It works fine offline (on supported devices) when I set [SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest#requiresOnDeviceRecognition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionrequest/3152603-requiresondevicerecognition) to true.

Q: Is there a way to configure it to use the online version if online and fall back to on-device recognition if offline?

Comment: Did you find a solution?